# Lodash groupBy with moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I am trying to group a bunch of dates by today, this week, this month and then previous months. However before I even get to this point I am struggling to get even a basic grouping by month.

```
const data = [{
 campaign: "Charles",
 company_ID: "1",
 coreURL: "http://www.test77.com",
 createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:45:56.931Z",
 owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
 updatedAt: "2017-09-06T20:45:56.931Z",
 _id: "6gsb42PSSJt7PgsDG"
}, {
 campaign: "Charles",
 company_ID: "1",
 coreURL: "http://www.test66,com",
 createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
 owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
 updatedAt: "2017-10-06T20:46:27.744Z",
 _id: "Md4wCnEsrQrWApnLS"
}, {
 campaign: "Gary",
 company_ID: "1",
 coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
 createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
 owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
 updatedAt: "2017-07-06T20:46:27.744Z",
 _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}
];

const grouper = 'updatedAt';

let groupedData = _
  .chain(data)
  .groupBy(datum => moment(datum.grouper).format("MM"))
```

EDIT: However this only seems to group by "11" (todays Month)

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`datum.grouper` is `undefined` so `moment(datum.grouper)` is returning the current date.

You should instead be using `datum[grouper]` or something like this `_.property('updatedAt')`.

Regarding your question about how to separate the dates into today, this week, this month, and other months, please try the below:

```js
const data = [{
  campaign: "Charles",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test77.com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:45:56.931Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-09-06T20:45:56.931Z",
  _id: "6gsb42PSSJt7PgsDG"
}, {
  campaign: "Charles",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test66,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-10-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "Md4wCnEsrQrWApnLS"
}, {
  campaign: "Gary",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-07-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}, {
  campaign: "Fred",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-11-15T03:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}, {
  campaign: "Fred",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-11-03T20:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}, {
  campaign: "Fred",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-11-13T20:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}, {
  campaign: "Fred",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-11-09T20:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}];

const groupProp = _.property('updatedAt');

let determineGroup = value => {
  // remove '2017-11-15' to actually use current date 
  const now = moment('2017-11-15T10:00:03Z').startOf('day');

  if (value.isSame(now, 'day')) {
    return 'today';
  }
  if (value.isAfter(now.clone().subtract(7, 'days').startOf('day'))) {
    return 'this week';
  }
  if (value.isSame(now, 'month')) {
    return 'this month';
  }
  return value.format('MM');
};

let groupedData = _
  .chain(data)
  .groupBy(datum => determineGroup(moment(groupProp(datum))))
  .value()

console.log(groupedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is great thanks. Do you have any thoughts as to how to group conditionally (ie. Today, this week, this month) :-)

Comment: @NickWild Would "this week" include the "today" items or exclude them? And would you define "this week" as "the past seven days" or "the time since a certain day of the week (Sunday/Monday)"? Similar questions regarding "this month".

Comment: This week would exclude today, maybe last 7 days rather than calendar week, but this month would be the actual month (but exclude the past 7 days) and then other historical months would just be the regular calendar months. Thanks!

Comment: @NickWild Ok, please see my updated answer. I've used a function to categorize the dates into the groups you've indicated.

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you for your time writing this code

Comment: I have assigned the .groupBy fat arrow function to a variable, so I can ascertain whether the groupBy is createdAt or another prop, but can't get this to work. I have asked for help on this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323874

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use filter if you only need to current month, day, year .

```
const today = _.filter(data, d => moment(d.updatedAt).isSame(moment(), 'day'));
console.log(today);

const thisWeek = _.filter(data, d => moment(d.updatedAt).isSame(moment(), 'week'));
console.log(thisWeek);

const thisMonth = _.filter(data, d => moment(d.updatedAt).isSame(moment(), 'month'));
console.log(thisMonth);
```

Or groupBy if you need all months (for all years)

```
const byMonth = _.groupBy(data, d => moment(d.updatedAt).month());
console.log(byMonth);
```

https://jsbin.com/xidido/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

```
let groupedData = _
.chain(data)
.groupBy(record => moment(record.updatedAt).format("MM"))
.value();
```