# Lodash groupBy fat arrow function with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

Following on from [Lodash groupBy with moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302248/) that groups an array by dates such as today, this week, month etc by using a fat arrow function and moment I am now trying to enable if then else (or ternary) that only enables this if the sort parameter (passed in from state) is actually a date.

This is what I have at the moment...

```
     let groupby = datum => {
        if (this.state.sortGroup ='updatedAt') {
          return determineGroup(moment(groupProp(datum)));
        } else {
          this.state.sortGroup
        }
      }

      //console log point 1 -  shows state change

      groupedData = _
      .chain(this.props.records)
      .groupBy(groupby)
      .map(function(val, key) {
          return {
              group: key,
              records: val
          };
      })
      .value()

      //console log point 2 -  no state change
```

It sorts by the grouped createdAt perfectly, but when I put the if then else functionality in it does not sort by any other prop. Also interestingly at log point 2 it does not show the state changing.

Is this something I am doing wrong that is affecting state or poor code in the if then else function?

Comment: You're using single equals for the first if (assignment) which might be one of your problems. In the else statement you're not returning this.state.sortGroup either.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :-) I had tried == and === and it does not sort at all. How should I return the this.state.sortGroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `sortGroup` refers to the name of a property on the data, in which case, I think you need something more like this:

```js
const data = [{
  campaign: "Charles",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test77.com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:45:56.931Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-09-06T20:45:56.931Z",
  _id: "6gsb42PSSJt7PgsDG"
}, {
  campaign: "Charles",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test66,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-10-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "Md4wCnEsrQrWApnLS"
}, {
  campaign: "Gary",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-07-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}, {
  campaign: "Fred",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-11-15T03:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}, {
  campaign: "Fred",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-11-03T20:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}, {
  campaign: "Fred",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-11-13T20:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}, {
  campaign: "Fred",
  company_ID: "1",
  coreURL: "http://www.test55,com",
  createdAt: "2017-11-06T20:46:27.744Z",
  owner: "K7xTxu7PRDCuhFZRC",
  updatedAt: "2017-11-09T20:46:27.744Z",
  _id: "5p44uiwRgqp35YXRf"
}];

const groupProp = _.property('updatedAt');

let determineGroup = value => {
  // remove '2017-11-15' to actually use current date 
  const now = moment('2017-11-15T10:00:03Z').startOf('day');

  if (value.isSame(now, 'day')) {
    return 'today';
  }
  if (value.isAfter(now.clone().subtract(7, 'days').startOf('day'))) {
    return 'this week';
  }
  if (value.isSame(now, 'month')) {
    return 'this month';
  }
  return value.format('MM');
};

this.state = {
  sortGroup: 'updatedAt'
};

let groupby = datum => {
  const groupValue = datum[this.state.sortGroup];

  if (this.state.sortGroup === 'updatedAt') {
    return determineGroup(moment(groupValue));
  } else {
    return groupValue;
  }
}

let groupedData = _
  .chain(data)
  .groupBy(groupby)
  .value()

console.log(groupedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @JLRishe. Yes this.state.sortGroup stores the result of a dropdown select that controls sorting. Stored in it could by createdAt, campaign etc. Your code does restore the grouping by other props but it breaks the sorting by today, this week, etc

Comment: @NickWild Seems to be working above. Are you trying to use the date-based grouping for properties other than `createdAt`?

Comment: Hi, no I'm not, and yes I agree if you manually enter createdAt or campaign etc into state.sortGroup all sorts OK so this code works (thanks) but this "if then else" code does seem to break the state and disable the dropdown from setting the state. Do you need to see anymore of the code?

Comment: @NickWild Maybe `state.sortGroup` isn't actually a string value. Could you try logging it to the console?

Comment: It appears to be a string from  - console log position 1:updatedAt and from console log position 2: updatedAt. But the dropdown that sets this state does not now set state. remove this function and it sets the state OK again

Comment: also if you remove your manual setting of this.state.sortGroup then the sorting returns but it does not group by today, week, month etc

Comment: Sorry for more noise on this, but if you console.log groupValue it would appear onlly to be set for any non createdAt prop (e.g. campaign) on the first iteration of the map. Subsequent iterations revert back to the date

Comment: @NickWild Could you post your full code somewhere like Plunkr? There's nothing in my code that should be changing the `groupValue` mid-operation.

Comment: Many thanks! I have put it on https://codesandbox.io/s/wkov7q88w8 There is a bizarre error that it does not load a sub-component on this platform, but at least you can see all the code.

Comment: @NickWild You're doing an assignment here: `if (this.state.sortGroup = 'updatedAt') {`. That would explain why `sortGroup` is changing. This is the same problem rrd pointed out 23 hours ago and a line that's definitely not in my code above.

Comment: Sorry I had not restored it back! It doesn't group with the today, week, month etc with == or ===

Comment: @NickWild I've fixed the compilation errors: https://codesandbox.io/s/k0ko9vp7v7 The today, week, month grouping was not working because that grouping is only applied when grouping on `updatedAt` and your group options did not include an option for `updatedAt`.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much.